# prevent git from converting LF to CRLF or vice versa - and restart converting when needed

Tags: git

I know there already are other answers but they are not straightforward.

Please help by providing a *single line of code* that **stops** git from converting LF to CRLF or vice versa so that my code can be pushed/fetched to/from the remote repo just as it was created on my computer.

kindly also help with providing the command to **revert** back this change so git can again start converting the line endings if I ever feel a need for it.

(I am using windows 10 pc with CodeBlocks IDE and after creating my program, while staging the local repository in git bash, this "warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF" popped up. **I have no big problem with this notification**, I just wish to **stop** his conversion completely for some time. I might want to **restart** it at some later point in time.)

Comment: The answers are not straightforward because the *problem* is not straightforward. You'll need to use those other answers.

Comment: There is no single line of code that does this.  There are multiple settings that control this feature and they are dependent on your platform and configuration in your repository.